# Is there a more ethical way of dong this?? Embedded in C - PIC16F18326 - MPLAB

Tags: c, embedded, mplab

there must be a better way of coding this, it all works but takes up alot of space, is there a more ethical way of doing it?

So to start with, my code basically flashes an led, it also has different speed setting that can be programmed via button presses.

So my program knows which mode it is in i have the following code which changes when the mode is changed, for example if changing to mode 5 from mode 1, M1 would = 0 and M5 would = 1 etc.

```
        M1 = 1; // We are in Mode 1
        M2 = 0;
        M3 = 0;
        M4 = 0;
        M5 = 0;
        M6 = 0;
        M7 = 0;
        M8 = 0;
        M9 = 0;
        M10 = 0;
        M11 = 0;
        M12 = 0;
        M13 = 0;
        M14 = 0;
        M15 = 0;
        M16 = 0;
        M17 = 0;
        M18 = 0;
```

Then when the speed is changed, the program would go through this chunk of code to save the speed to whatever mode it was in at the time. This way i can have different speeds saved to different modes. Again this is alot of code and im sure im over-complicating it. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
void Speeds(void)
{            
    if (M1 == 1) // if in mode 1 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S1; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M2 == 1) // if in mode 2 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S2; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M3 == 1) // if in mode 3 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S3; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M4 == 1) // if in mode 4 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S4; // save value to this mode only   
    }

    if (M5 == 1) // if in mode 5 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S5; // save value to this mode only   
    }

    if (M6 == 1) // if in mode 6 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S6; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M7 == 1) // if in mode 7 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S7; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M8 == 1) // if in mode 8 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S8; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M9 == 1) // if in mode 9 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S9; // save value to this mode only   
    }

    if (M10 == 1) // if in mode 10 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S10; // save value to this mode only   
    }

    if (M11 == 1) // if in mode 11 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S11; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M12 == 1) // if in mode 12 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S12; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M13 == 1) // if in mode 13 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S13; // save value to this mode only
    }

    if (M14 == 1) // if in mode 14 when changing speed
    {
        counter = S14; // save value to this mode only   
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have a single variable called mode instead of 18 different variables?

Comment: There's very little context here, but why not just one `mode` variable?

Comment: Depends on where these Mx and Sx are coming from. It is likely that these variables are totally useless and can be replaced with single variable. In any case that could be arrays at the very least, and then this could become a very simple loop of 2-3 lines.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: A single `M` variable instead of 18 different `Mn` variables and an array instead of a lot of `Sn` variables should do the job. The whole thing should take 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So a single variable for M that goes from M1-M18 instead?

And an array for the S, wouldnt that be the same though? I would save space on the first declarations but the coding would still be:

if (M == 4) // if in mode 4 when changing speed
        {
        counter = myArray[4]; // save value to this mode only   
        }

Comment: No, you would not use hard coded index values. If `mode==4` then you can use `counter = myArray[mode];` and drop 90% of your code.

Comment: The code might be something like `if((M >= minValue) && (M <= maxValue)) { counter = myArray[M]; }`. Note that in C an array index range is from 0 to (number of elements - 1), so it might be easier if the range of `M` is be 0..17 instead of 1..18. With an unsigned variable and minValue=0 you need to check for maxValue only.

Comment: Unfortunately your code is way too incomplete. You didn't answer the question where `Mx` and `Sx` come from. Is `Sx` a macro, a register value, a variable? Can it change?

Comment: char myModes[18];  // before main          

// in mode 1
myModes[] = 0; // make all values in array 0 
myModes[0] = 1; // set the first number in the array to 1

The above doesnt work though. 

Basically, i have 18 modes but to be able to save different speeds to those 18 modes i need the program to know which mode it is in. In every mode so far i set it like this:

Comment: // Mode 1
     M1 = 1; // We are in Mode 1
            M2 = 0;
            M3 = 0;
            M4 = 0;
            M5 = 0;
            M6 = 0;
            M7 = 0;
            M8 = 0;
            M9 = 0;
            M10 = 0;
            M11 = 0;
            M12 = 0;
            M13 = 0;
            M14 = 0;
            M15 = 0;
            M16 = 0;
            M17 = 0;
            M18 = 0;

Comment: // Mode 2
     M1 = 0; 
            M2 = 1; // We are in Mode 2
            M3 = 0;
            M4 = 0;
            M5 = 0;
            M6 = 0;
            M7 = 0;
            M8 = 0;
            M9 = 0;
            M10 = 0;
            M11 = 0;
            M12 = 0;
            M13 = 0;
            M14 = 0;
            M15 = 0;
            M16 = 0;
            M17 = 0;
            M18 = 0;

And so on... all the way to mode 18. So the program knows which mode its in by Mxx being set to 1

Comment: Sx is just a place i store a number. For example, Say i changed to speed in mode 6 (M6) to 10, i would put S6 = 10; so 10 is saved there for callback later if needed

Comment: Why do you need 18 different variables if the program can only be in one single mode at a time? None of this makes any sense and none of your explanations contract replacing this whole thing with `uint8_t mode;` and `uint16_t counter[18];` where `mode` can be used as array index for `counter`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to change the representation of the mode that use one variable to represent different mode? For example:

```
Mode = 0  <=>  M1 = 1
Mode = 1  <=>  M2 = 1
Mode = 2  <=>  M3 = 1
....
Mode = 17  <=> M18 = 1
```

If it is possible, then the if-else statements in the Speeds() function can be replaced to the switch-case statement. Then the expression will become concise. For example:

```
switch(Mode){
    case 0:
      counter = S1; // save value to this mode only
      break;
    case 1:
      counter = S2; // save value to this mode only
      break;
     ...
    case 17:
      counter = S18; // save value to this mode only
      break;

}
```

Comment: By putting the constants `S1`to `S18` in an array like `int S[] = {S1, S2, ..., S18};`, the whole code would be a single line: `counter = S[Mode];`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I would add a check for the maximum value of `Mode` to avoid out-of-bounds access to the array.